# Getting js error with IE 9 and 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ckeditor, permission-denied

When we click on one of our jsp page textarea, we load the ckeditor in that textarea. After cancelling it, we unload the ckeditor from the area and make it a simple text area. Then we attempt to load the ckeditor the second time, and it gives a js error.

What is this error?

We are using ckedtor v4.0.

We got the following js error only with IE 9/10 browser.

> Message: Permission denied
>   Line: 50
>   Char: 375
>   Code: 0
>   URI:ckeditor.js

After checking in the ckeditor.js file, we got the line and took a snippet

```js
getDocument:function()
{
    return new CKEDITOR.dom.document(this.$.ownerDocument||this.$.parentNode.ownerDocument) //error getting at above line
}
```

How can we get rid of this error?

Can anybody give us the solution of this js error to us. It is critical for us.

Comment: are you loading it from a different domain?

Comment: Hi i have not IE 10 in my PC, so I just connect remote computer, and Use that remote computer IE 10 browser to access my instance, can this cause the said issue?

Comment: Hi anyone having update on the above issue? , i am still looking for the solution

Comment: I have downloaded ckeditor 4.4 and the issue is still there at least for IE11

Answer (score 0):

I received this error on IE 8 running this code:

```
var range = selection.getRanges()[0];
range.moveToBookmark(bookmarks[0]);
range.select();
```

Specifically the last line.

The solution was to wrap that around a settimeout possibly because IE8 doesn't have a hold of that element at that time so the above becomes:

```
var range = selection.getRanges()[0];
range.moveToBookmark(bookmarks[0]);
window.setTimeout(function () { range.select(); }, 10);
```

A ticket on ckeditor is open for this see http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10501